# Emulating Ctrl + Spacebar + AlphabeticalKey with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

My problem :

```
^space & c::
send {F2} 
send {Escape}
```

but it didn't work, how do I emulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> + AlphabeticaklKey ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As my previous speakers said, it can't be done easily. Here's my suggestion, it seems to work fine:

```
^space::
    Loop {
        if(GetKeyState("c")) {
            break
        }
        if(!GetKeyState("CTRL") || !GetKeyState("SPACE")) {
            return
        }
        Sleep, 50
    }
    msgbox, You have pressed CTRL+SPACE+C
return
```

The code is pretty self-explanatory. When <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is pressed, it waits until either one of both is released or <kbd>C</kbd> is pressed. The latter triggers the actual functionality, otherwise it will return.
I actually don't like it very much, because theoretically it may fail in some cases (e.g. when <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is pressed and released before the execution reaches the check for the state of <kbd>C</kbd>; although that seems very unlikely).

### Update

There's also a way using `#If`. I recommend using that since it's more sophisticated and reliable. This is due to the fact that it doesn't need any loops:

```
#If GetKeyState("SPACE")
^c::Msgbox, You have pressed CTRL+SPACE+C

#If GetKeyState("c")
^space::Msgbox, You have pressed CTRL+SPACE+C
```

Comment: IMHO this adds unnecessary complexity. Just taking another "hotkeyable" key like windows or alt would do the job perfectly.

Comment: @ikaros45 I agree that using a "native" key combination would be easier and probably less error-prone. Then again, OP wanted to combine two non-modifier keys and that's what he gets ;)

Comment: This answer would also work for my more general question here: http://superuser.com/questions/762273/autohotkey-organizing-hotkeys-so-as-to-use-several-hotkeys-optimally

Comment: @Stenemo You're welcome to abstract my solution and propose it as an answer on SU.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only combine two non-hotkey keys with the syntax:

```
space & c:: msgbox space and c
```

You can read it [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

> You can define a custom combination of two keys (except joystick
>   buttons) by using & between them. In the below example, you would hold
>   down Numpad0 then press the second     key to trigger the hotkey:
>
> Numpad0 & Numpad1::MsgBox You pressed Numpad1 while holding down
>   Numpad0. Numpad0 & Numpad2::Run Notepad

Trying to use control as well like in: `space & c & control` or `space & ^c` or any other combination will result in compile error.

My recommendation is that you don't combine that three keys together. Look for a pure hotkey combination or use another more or less useless key.

- `#!c::` windows + alt + c
- `AppsKey & c::`

Remember that if you use a normal key as modificator, you have to remap it to itself to keep the original functionality, for example with the menu key (appskey):

```
AppsKey:: Send {Appskey}
AppsKey & c:: ;do what you want
```

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a couple ways to get help. First of all the authors of this language have moved to a new domain [ahkscript.org](http://ahkscript.org). It is always welcome to ask questions like these in our forum. I just happened to be digging through this site today and saw this by accident.

When you have more than one line of code after a hotkey you need to have a return follow it:

```
^space & c::
send {F2} 
send {Escape}
return
```

Hope that helps